# regular expression for matching a list of strings

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regular expressions. I managed to solve a range of integers, but now I need something to match this:

```
{anystring, anystring, anystring}
```

Including brackets and for not only 3 items, but for any number.

Comment: What characters are allowed in 'anystring'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^\{[^ ,]+(, [^ ,]+)*\}$
```

Assuming that your list contains at least one item and each item is followed by a comma and a space (", "). If you only want each item to be followed by a comma, use [jjnguy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433575/regular-expression-for-matching-a-list-of-strings/4433624#4433624) solution.

Here's my attempt at an explanation at what's going on in this pattern:

- The `[^]` expression matches anything that **does not** follow the caret `^`. So `[^ ,]` will match anything except for a space or a comma.
- `+` means "match the previous thing 1 or more times". So `[^ ,]+` will match any sequence of characters that do not contain a comma or a space.
- `*` means "match the previous thing 0 or more times". So, `(, [^ ,]+)*` will match 0 or more occurrences of the pattern `, [^ ,]+` -- a sequence beginning with a comma and a space, followed by a sequence of at least one character (that does not contain any commas or spaces).
- Wrapping it all in `^\{` and `\}$` ensures that the string begins with a left curly brace and ends with a right curly brace.

See [this page](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) for a useful "cheat sheet" on regular expressions.

Comment: I corrected the spelling on _jjnguy_ 's name.  Hopefully I didn't mess with any edits you were in the process of making.

Comment: @Jeff M jjnguy, gotcha -- I blame kerning :) No worries; I was just trying to clarify that third bullet point.

Comment: Cheers for the expression and useful comments and link!

Answer (score 1):

The following will (should) match any number of char sequences separated by comas and enclosed in curly braces.

```
@"\{([^,]+, )*([^,]+)\}"
```

This assumes that the list will always contain one item.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
String src = "{one, two, three}";
String[] result = src.Substring(1, src.Length - 2).Split(", ");
```